# Google+ ios like drop down from action bar in android

Tags: android, toolbar

I would like to implement a drop down menu from the ToolBar like in the Ios version of Google+:[image: Google+ ios]

But as as a beginner in android development, I don't know which component should I use, anybody can help me with that ?

Comment: Ask to `Google` or `Bing`

Comment: Ofcourse I do ask this to google but unfortunately i can't find a correct answer to this, I only found a similar question here on stackoverflow but th only answer was: "You should not do that" or "it's not keeping the android guidelines"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those SO question you've mentioned in the comments are true: You should *not* implement an exact copy of that iOS navigation in Android. If you choose to develop an app for Android then you better make it look like an Android app (because that is what your users will expect).

However, that does not imply Android lacks of similar navigation pattern. What you are looking for is `ActionBar` dropdown navigation and can be found on [this official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown). That link should be enough to get you started. :)